# How can I combine IApplyToTest with TestFixtureSource to get descendant tests?

Tags: nunit, nunit-3.0

I have a custom attribute:

```cs
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
sealed class MyAttribute : NUnitAttribute, IApplyToTest
{
    // ...

    public void ApplyToTest(Test test)
    {
        // I need to get all descendant tests of parameter 'test' here.
    }

    // ...
}
```

If I combine it with a `TestFixture` attribute like this, things work as expected:

```cs
[TestFixture(1)]
[TestFixture(2)]
[MyAttribute]
class MyTests
{
    // ...
}
```

`ApplyToTest` is then called with a `TestFixture`, which has a non-empty `test.Tests` property which I can use to recursively get all descendant tests.

However, if I use `TestFixtureSource`, this approach breaks down:

```cs
[TestFixtureSource(nameof(GetTestFixtureSource))]
[MyAttribute]
class MyTests
{
    static IEnumerable<int> GetTestFixtureSource() => new List<int>() { 1, 2 };

    // ...
}
```

Now, `ApplyToTest` is called with a `ParameterizedFixtureSuite` which has an empty `test.Tests` property.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

So I've found somewhat of a solution, or at least a workaround.

The attribute needs to be changed like this:

```cs
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Assembly | AttributeTargets.Class)]
sealed class MyAttribute : NUnitAttribute, IApplyToTest
{
    // ...
}
```

Instead of a test class, it needs to be applied to the assembly:

```cs
[assembly: MyAttribute]
```

Now, `ApplyToTest` is called with a `TestAssembly`, which has a non-empty `test.Tests` property which I can use to recursively get all tests.